# Input text tooltip doesn't show up

Tags: css, text, input, tooltip

I'm going to add the tooltip for the input text in the page, this page has their own css!
my code is work on local machine but when i pasted code on that page it doesn't work, it seems there is a conflict on the page, but i've ran out of finding the issue.

the js is :

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // execute your scripts when the DOM is ready. this is a good habit
  $(function() {

        // select all desired input fields and attach tooltips to them
      $("#myform :input").tooltip({

      // place tooltip on the right edge
      position: "center right",

      // a little tweaking of the position
      offset: [-2, 10],

      // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
      effect: "fade",

      });
    });
</script>
```

the css is :

```
  #myform {
  }
  .tooltip{

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #bbb #bbb #a8a8a8;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 255px;
  line-height: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 16px;
  top: 48px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
  }
```

and the code is :

```
<form id="myform" action="#">
    <!-- username -->
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" title="Must be at least 8 characters."/>
</form>
```

and below is the current input css of the page:

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 46px;
    width: 83%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite style by adding your own  .tooltip style and overwriting each style using !important .  do it for each style in .tooltip.   hope this help.   here is a simple [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/4YFNf/).

```
.tooltip{
     background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a JS issue, it doesn't work with !important . .

Comment: i found the problem, there is another class in my CSS called tooltip, i can't change that name but when i change the tooltip name in my JS and also css the code doesn't work again.